# Compile time efficient remove duplicates from a boost::hana tuple

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, boost-hana

I use the `boost::hana` `to_map` function to remove duplicates from `boost::hana` tuple of types. See it at the [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/1Y1xnn). The code works very well but compiles very long (~10s). I wonder if there exist a faster solution that is compatible with `boost::hana` tuple.

```cpp
#include <boost/hana/map.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/pair.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/type.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/basic_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/size.hpp>

using namespace boost::hana;

constexpr auto to_type_pair = [](auto x) { return make_pair(typeid_(x), x); };

template <class Tuple>
constexpr auto remove_duplicate_types(Tuple tuple)
{
    return values(to_map(transform(tuple, to_type_pair)));
}


int main(){

    auto tuple = make_basic_tuple(
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
        , 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
        , 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
        , 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40
        , 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50
        , 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60
        , 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70
        );

    auto noDuplicatesTuple = remove_duplicate_types(tuple);

    // Should return 1 since there is only one distinct type in the tuple
    return size(noDuplicatesTuple);
}
```

Comment: Is it important to use boost::hana? Is it a real case or just an example? If you only have integers in your tuple, you could probably just use std::array and then implement simple N^2 constexpr algorithm.

Comment: The above code is just a simplified example. I need the function for a state machine library where the tuple is a tuple of state types, so not just integer. The algorithm itself does not need to be made with `boost::hana` but it must interface with `boost::hana` tuple.

Comment: Are you wanting to retain the corresponding run-time value of the first of every unique T in your tuple?

Comment: I need both versions. So I would be happy if there is a more efficient version for one version.

Comment: Sad, https://build-bench.com/ doesn't support boost/hana (yet?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't run any benchmarks, but your example does not appear to take 10 seconds on Compiler Explorer. However, I can explain why it is a relatively slow solution, and suggest an alternative that assumes you are only interested getting a unique list of types and not retaining any run-time information in your result.

Creating large tuples and/or instantiating function templates that have large tuples in their prototypes are expensive compile-time operations.

Just your call to `transform` instantiates a lambda for each element which in turn instantiates pair. The input/output of this call are both large tuples.

The call to `to_map` makes an empty `map` and recursively calls `insert` for each element each time making a new `map`, but in this simple case the intermediate result will always be `hana::map<int>`. I'm willing to bet that this is exploding your compile-times if your actual use case is non-trivial. (It was certainly an issue when we were implementing `hana::map` so we made `hana::make_map` avoid this since it has all of its inputs up front).

All of this, and there is a significant penalty for these large function types being used in run-time code. You might notice a difference if you wrapped the operations in `decltype` and only used the resulting type.

Alternatively, using raw template metaprogramming can sometimes yield performance results over function template based metaprogramming. Here is an example for your use case:

```
#include <boost/hana/basic_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/mp11/algorithm.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;
using namespace boost::mp11;


int main() {
    auto tuple = hana::make_basic_tuple(
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
        , 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
        , 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
        , 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40
        , 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50
        , 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60
        , 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70
        );

    hana::basic_tuple<int> no_dups = mp_unique<std::decay_t<decltype(tuple)>>{};
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/EnTWf6