# Neatly linking dependency tuple references specified by variadic class args

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

Given the following class structure in which we possess a number of different classes `C#`, each with unique data that is passed into a number of ledgers `L<C#>`, as well as possessing a number of classes `S#`, each depending on some subset of the classes under the `C#`, I have established a tuple containing all ledgers in the manager class `E`.

```cpp
// Dependency classes
struct C {};
struct C1 : C {};
struct C2 : C {};

// Dependency data ledger
template <class T>
class L {};

// Dependency user
template <class... Cs>
struct S {
  using Deps = std::tuple<Cs...>;
  using DepRefs = std::tuple<L<Cs>&...>;
};
struct S1 : S<C1> {};
struct S2 : S<C1, C2> {};

// Manager
template <class... Ss>
class E;
template <class... Ss>
class E : public E<all_deps_no_duplicates<Ss...>, Ss...> {};
template <class... Cs, class... Ss>
class E<std::tuple<Cs...>, Ss...> {
  std::tuple<L<Cs>...> DepsData;
  std::tuple<typename Ss::DepsRefs...> DepsRefs; // Problem instantiation.
};

// Usage
int main() { E<S1, S2> e; };
```

What elegant solutions exist then to establish a secondary tuple containing references to each one of each dependency user's dependency ledgers? There are no duplicates in the tuple of dependency ledgers with one ledger per dependency with perhaps many dependency users each. For example, in the code given, I would want the first and second tuples in the manager class `E` to respectively contain:

`DepsData:`

```cpp
std::tuple<
  L<C1>(), // 1st element: a ledger for C1
  L<C2>()  // 2nd element: a ledger for C2
>
```

`DepsRefs:`

```cpp
std::tuple<
  std::tuple<L<C1>&>,         // tuple containing reference to DepsData 1st element
  std::tuple<L<C1>&, L<C2>&>  // tuple containing reference to DepsData 1st and 2nd elements
>
```

With both `L<C1>&` references in `DepsRefs` referring to the same ledger specified in `DepsData`.

Comment: As I understand, you have two issues here: `all_deps_no_duplicates<Ss...>` (Related to [compile-time-efficient-remove-duplicates-from-a-boosthana-tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65269952/compile-time-efficient-remove-duplicates-from-a-boosthana-tuple)), and instantiate `DepsRefs` with reference to `DepsData` (as types are unique in `DepsData`, `std::get<Ts>(DepsData)...` should do the jobs).

Comment: @Jarod42, `all_deps_no_duplicates` has already been handled elsewhere in the code. The only issue is the instantiation of `DepsRefs` with `DepsData`. I've taken a look at `get`, and while if I had the raw individual variadic type lists of each `S`, I could see myself doing something along the lines of `DepsRef{ get<S::DepsRaw>(DepsData)... }` for a single `S`'s dependencies, given `S::Deps` is a tuple and even if not, I can't "double-expand" `DepsRef{ tuple{get<Ss::DepsRaw>(DepsData)...}... }` for each `S`'s would-be `DepsRaw` as well as each `S` in `Ss`, I don't see how to implement it.

Comment: Furthermore, apologies for any imprecise terminology. I'm still learning to navigate template metaprogramming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So focusing on the reference initialization, you might do something like:

```
template <typename T> struct Tag{};

template <typename... Ts, typename Tuple>
std::tuple<L<Ts>&...> make_ref_tuple(Tag<std::tuple<L<Ts>&...>>, Tuple& tuple)
{
    return {std::get<L<Ts>>(tuple)...};
}

template <class... Cs, class... Ss>
class E<std::tuple<Cs...>, Ss...> {
  std::tuple<L<Cs>...> DepsData;
  std::tuple<typename Ss::DepsRefs...> DepsRefs =
     { make_ref_tuple(Tag<typename Ss::DepsRefs>{}, DepsData)... };
};
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1d193b129abb554)

Comment: This solution worked perfectly. Thank you sincerely for your help. I'm fairly certain I've also indirectly been assisted by you from your answers on other `[variadic-templates]` tagged questions, so I'd like to thank you for that as well while you're here. :)